# how to set react native button to full width

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have tried all of the examples out there but I can not figure it out. I am using this https://github.com/xinthink/react-native-material-kit

If I use the dimensions as the width the button width goes off screen. I would like if possible to have the logo at the very top and the form and button at the very button. this is for android only.

```
 const btnStyle = {
btn: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row"
    //resizeMode: 'cover'
}
};
const ColoredRaisedButton = MKButton.coloredButton()
.withStyle(btnStyle.btn)
.build();

<ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
<View style={styles.container}>
    {/* Here the magic happens*/}
    <View style={styles.cardStyle}>
        <Image
            source={require("./../img/logo_login.jpg")}
            style={styles.cardImageStyle}
        />
        <View style={styles.cardContentStyle}>
            <Form
                ref="form"
                type={User}
                onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)}
                value={this.state.value}
                options={options}
            />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.cardActionStyle}>
            <ColoredRaisedButton>
                <Text pointerEvents="none" style={styles.buttonText}>
                    BUTTON
                </Text>
            </ColoredRaisedButton>
        </View>
    </View>
</View>
</ScrollView>;

const styles = {
cardStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#ffffff",
    borderRadius: 2,
    borderColor: "#ffffff",
    borderWidth: 1,
    shadowColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.12)",
    shadowOpacity: 0.8,
    shadowRadius: 2,
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center",
    shadowOffset: {
        height: 1,
        width: 2
    }
},
cardImageStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    height: 170,
    flexDirection: "row",
    resizeMode: "cover"
},
cardContentStyle: {
    padding: 15 //,
    // bottom:0,
    // position:'absolute',
    //justifyContent: 'flex-end'
},
cardActionStyle: {
    flex: 1,
    borderStyle: "solid",
    borderTopColor: "rgba(0,0,0,.1)",
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    padding: 15,
    alignItems: "center",
    flexDirection: "column",
    justifyContent: "center"
},
scrollView: {
    flex: 1
},
container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "stretch",
    backgroundColor: "#eae9e9",
    padding: 20 //,
    //position:'absolute'
},
buttonText: {
    fontSize: 14,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    color: "white"
}
};
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should remove the `alignItems: 'center'` from both `cardStyle` & `cardActionStyle`, then you should get a full width button.

Comment: almost perfect! it works for the button but then it messes up the image. any ideas how to do both

Answer (score 7):

You can use this pattern:

```
<View style={[{width:"100%"}]}>
    <Button
        onPress={this.closeModal}
        title="Close"
        color="#841584"
        style={[{borderRadius: 5,}]}
        hardwareAccelerated
    />
</View>
```

Answer (score 3):

Set Button Width and Height In React Native
Lets use the below source that helps to set width and height of button. Here you need to specify the button width and height parameter in view layout.

```
<View style={[{ width: "90%", margin: 10, backgroundColor: "red" }]}>
   <Button
      onPress={this.buttonClickListener}
      title="Button Three"
      color="#90A4AE"
    />
</View>
```

Answer (score -1):

In the last version of react-native-elements (currently the **2.0.2**) to add some nice styles to button, you can use the attributes titleStyle(for the text) and buttonStyle(for the layout) and then you will be able to write something like width:'100%'

```
<Button title="My great button" type="solid"  buttonStyle={{marginTop: 32, borderColor: 'red', borderWidth: 1, width: '100%', paddingVertical: 8}} titleStyle={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold'}} />
```